# Maintain selected tab after page reload in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a page with a tab component, with 5 tabs in it.

What would be the best way to maintain the state of which tab was selected after a page reload/refresh in React/Redux?

I can think of two ways to persist this:

- Query parameters
- Local storage

Are these okay to use or is there a better/more React way to do this?

Comment: my vote goes for query params. that way you can open the page to the correct tab and people that don't use localstorage still get same behaviour

Comment: I am currently facing the same situation where I would like my previously selected tab to stay selected upon and post reload. Would you mind sharing that chunk of code if possible so that I can deconstruct and adapt it to my own? It would be of great help, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first say that it's a highly opinionated question and depends on your design and needs.

I would use query parameters if the current tab is an important information on reload, since it could also be a link shared, opened in another browser...

I usually use local storage to store internal state about the application (such as login, show a popup on an element the first time its seen to explain what it does, etc...), not if a tab has been selected or not, since it's quite a versatile information. The user might for example get to the page from another page, later, and still get the second tab open instead of the default one.